# Regex pattern to ignore multiple folders

Tags: npm, electron, electron-packager

How is the correct syntax to ignore more then one files and folders for [electron-packager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-packager)?

With only one arg like: `--ignore=docs/*` it works fine. But I want to ignore more then one folder and files like: `--ignore=docs/* + dev/* + someFile.js`

Answer (score 3):

This variant works for me

`--ignore=\"(docs*|dev*|somefile\.js)\"`

Answer (score 1):

Use the OR statement in the regular expression by using the | character in stead of the + character.

```
--ignore="docs/.*|dev/.*|somefile\.js"
```

Comment: this don't work. I saw that electron-packager support an array of regex, but all variations I tried end up with an error. For now I use the --ignore flag multiple times with one arg

Comment: @Zantinger I just changed the regex, I saw I made a mistake. I added the dot before the asterisk, now it will capture any character, in my previous regex it would just capture multiple slashes. Could you try again?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone out there who's looking for a simpler way of packaging an Angular application with Electron using electron-packager, this might get you sorted.

```
$ electron-packager . myapp --out=dist/builds/win --arch=x64 --icon=src/assets/images/win_icon.ico --asar --overwrite --ignore="(node_modules*|dist/builds*|dist/installers*|e2e*|src*)"
```

It works for me all the time, I use the terminal from VS Code.