# regEx to ignore build and dist directories at top level of project?

Tags: javascript, regex, electron, electron-packager

This is a very basic question but I've been struggling with it for a while.

I'm trying to ignore the build and dist folders at the top level of my project. I've read the `electron packager` docs for [ignore](https://github.com/electron/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md#ignore) but `regex` just eludes me. I saw this earlier question [Regex pattern to ignore multiple folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039480/regex-pattern-to-ignore-multiple-folders) but the solutions there haven't worked for me.

I've tried the arg below but that seems to also delete all "dist" folders in the project, includng ones in the `node_modules` folder.

```
--ignore=dist/*
```

Little help?

Answer (score 1):

You can user RegEx alterations to separate each match with a "|" character:

regular expression syntax: `--ignore='node_module|dist|embedded\.js'`

Cheers.

~G